# How to know all indirect jars (not directly part of maven dependency) references in maven project

Tags: java, maven, jar, reference

I'm working on Blackduck remediations and unable to find which jar internally uses org.apache.thrift:libfb303:0.9.0. Particular libfb is not directly part of pom dependency. So I just wanted to know, internally which jar has a reference of it.

Apache Thrift0.9.0
maven: org.apache.thrift:libfb303:0.9.0
4 Known Vulnerability

**Short Term Upgrade Recommendation**
0.9.1
Vulnerabilities  3 1

**Long Term Upgrade Recommendation**
0.9.1

Comment: Ask maven for the dependency graph.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Maven Dependency Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html) for that.

Add the dependency to your `pom.xml` and simply run:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Comment: Even we can see child jar dependencies under(pom.xml tab) "Dependency Hierarchy" in eclipse.